# Save record from dictionary using MongoAlchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mongoalchemy

My model class for user collection looks like this.

```
class User(UserMixin,db.Document):
    config_extra_fields = 'ignore'
    first_name = StringField()
    last_name = StringField()
    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.mongo_id)
```

To insert value to this collection I use the following code:

```
user = User(first_name="FN", last_name="LN", finale_name="SOMENAME")
user.save()
```

I tried `setattr`, But it is ignoring the attributes that are not defined in the class.

Its working fine and even the `finale_name` is added to the document. 
However, I am unable to insert it dynamically.

Can I insert a dictionary to mongo using that class?
Something like this?

```
user = User({
        "first_name": "NEW NAME",
        "last_name": "LAST NAME",
        "username": "USER NAME",
        "one_more": "Hello"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
data = {
        "first_name": "NEW NAME",
        "last_name": "LAST NAME",
        "username": "USER NAME",
        "one_more": "Hello"
       }

user = User(**data)
```